# Public value does not updated when going back to code (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, public

Public variable did not updates when Form is closed and code navigates back to macro.

I have form created with only two buttons "Yes" and "No". When users click "No" I want to have a variable set to false and in case of "Yes" it will be true.

Here is WorksheetCode

```vb
Public bool As Boolean

Sub test2()
    Claims.Show

    If bool = True Then
        Range("A1") = "Yes"
    ElseIf bool = False Then
        Range("A1") = "No"
    Else
        Range("A1") = "Nothing"
    End If
End Sub
```

Below Form from which I want a value

```vb
Priate Sub No_Click()
    bool = False
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Yes_Click()    
    bool = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: public variable have to be in the same module that all the sub which need to use it. 

So you need to regroup those 3 sub

Comment: @Dorian No, but the public variable has to be in a module not in the worksheet code to be available globally in all modules. If it is in a module it is available an **all** modules.

Comment: If you make a sub in a module and have that sub set the value your sheet code can see it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I feal like I had an issue when I used a public var into an other module

Comment: @Dorian you feel wrong ;)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ meh, I will try it ASAP ^^ But i feel like I trust you ;)

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` in all your modules?  That will help.

Comment: does that say `Pirate Sub`? I think you misspelled `Private`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for you insight! I've tried to declare a public variable in module not in worksheet and it is working now! Great :D

Comment: @TimWilliams no I did not have ```Option Explicit``` in all modules

Comment: Then you should add it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare the variable in a module not in `ThisWorkbook`.

   ```
   Public bool As Boolean 'in a module
   ```
2. The procedure `Test2` then can be in `ThisWorkbook`:

   ```
   Sub test2()
       Claims.Show

       If bool Then
           Range("A1") = "Yes"
       Else
           Range("A1") = "No"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   Note that `bool` can only be `True` or `False` there is no 3ʳᵈ option. So It can be reduced. Also note that you shoud specify the sheet for your ranges like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Yes"` otherwise Excel uses which sheet ever is active.
3. Your procedures for the buttons where ever you want to put them

   ```
   Private Sub No_Click()
       bool = False
       Unload Me
   End Sub

   Private Sub Yes_Click()    
       bool = True
       Unload Me
   End Sub
   ```

I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. That would have generated a warning to prevent this issue.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning appropriate syntax for global variable?  E.g., you have `Public blah` in module `gvar`, you would then write `gvar.blah` when referencing.  If not using `Option Explicit`, you could technically be utilizing a *new* variable specific to your current module.

Comment: @Cyril You can test it but I believe if `Option Explicit` is off and you declare a public variable in a module, it will always use the declared variable instead of gerenrating a local new one.

Comment: that is true *when you understand the difference between a standard module and everything else* ;-)  that said qualifying *everything* is a very good idea anyway.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Well, that's true. Full qualifying is always a good idea :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tested and it does recognize the generic public variable (`blah`) without the module qualification.  One thing that is worth mentioning is that you can have public variables *with the same name* in each module, so you need to appropriately qualify.  `Public blah as string` in one module and `Public blah as long` in another... makes for an interesting day when trying to decipher another person's code.

Comment: Forgot to add, that gives a `type mismatch` if you don't qualify when people use the same variable as public across multiple modules.